# Notation about a specific functor

Tags: category-theory, notation

Let $\mathbf{1}$ be the category of one object, and let $\mathscr{C}$ be any category with an object of interest, say $A$.

Is there a commonly used notation for a functor $F: \mathbf{1} \to \mathscr{C}$ such that $F$ "picks" our object $A$?

Comment: In [Notes on Category Theory (Paolo Perrone)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10642v6), definition 3.1.1, the same symbol is used for the functor as for the picked object.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks! if you want to give that as an answer I'll certainly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Notes on Category Theory (Paolo Perrone)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10642v6), definition 3.1.1, the same symbol is used for the functor as for the picked object.

Comment: I also saw this in some other texts as well. It is also *very* common in the case that $\mathscr{C}$ is discrete and small. So if $X$ is a set, elements $x \in X$ are identified with their morphisms $x : 1 \to X$, and in ETCS this is how you actually *define* an element of a set. Accordingly, in theories such as ETCC it is reasonable to define an object of a category $\mathscr{C}$ to be a functor $1 \to \mathscr{C}$ where $ 1$ is the terminal category.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. It's also in harmony with how we could write for example $f+2$ for some function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and implicitly mean that $2$ is the constant function $x \mapsto 2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}.$